# Test execution randomly aborted by an issue originated in the request-pipeline of Hammerhead (Testcafe e2e tests)

Tags: node.js, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

thank you for looking into this!

We are running a quite comprehensive testsuite (some hunderds of test) with the goal to make sure that our tracking implemantation works as expected. We are executing this tests via CI 4x a day. Since a few weeks we have random test aborts, which are unfortunately extremely hard to track and reproduce.

### What is the Current behavior?

```
Errors: Unhandled promise rejection:

Error [ERR_HTTP2_INVALID_SESSION]: The session has been destroyed

at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)

at ClientHttp2Session.request (node:internal/http2/core:1702:13)
at DestinationRequest._sendRealThroughHttp2 (/home/ec2-user/actions-runner/_work/ds_cerberus/ds_cerberus/node_modules/testcafe-hammerhead/lib/request-pipeline/destination-request/index.js:51:32)
at DestinationRequest._send (/home/ec2-user/actions-runner/_work/ds_cerberus/ds_cerberus/node_modules/testcafe-hammerhead/lib/request-pipeline/destination-request/index.js:110:18)
at runMicrotasks (:null:null)

at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

For us it looks like a racing condition inside the hammerhead-lib which is used as a proxy for testcafe. But we have no idea how to fix this - or least make sure that not the whole suite of tests is aborted by it.

This is the stacktrace if the tests are aborted. Unfortunately this means that the execution of all tests is aborted and does not only affect a single test, which renders the whole suite for us pretty useless...

### Steps to Reproduce

There seems to be more aborts if the tests are executed in the suite and not solely - but even there it is quite hard to identify a pattern.

### TestCafe version

"testcafe": "^1.17.1",

### Node.js version

node-version: '16.x'

### Command-line arguments

testcafe --config-file .testcaferc-dev.json tests

Answer (score 2):

The issue may be related to HTTP/2 requests. So, you can disable it using the following option: [disableHttp2](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file#disablehttp2). Check if the issue is reproduced after that.

You can also try to increase timeouts, e.g. [ajaxRequestTimeout](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file#ajaxrequesttimeout) and [testExecutionTimeout](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file#testexecutiontimeout).

If this does not help, please create a simple project where the issue is reproducible and share it here. We will research it on our side.

Comment: Thank you very much - we will try and let you know!